# MobileFirst Platform adapter invocation fails in simulator

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I have a sample project "Invoking  adapter Procedures" in MobileFirst Platform. It receives feed and shows value while previewing in the MFP Console, but after  adding the iPad environment and running it in Xcode it does not fetch any feed and instead shows an error in the Xcode console:

> Cannot fetch feed

and in the iOS Simulator:

> service not available

**Adapter code**

```
<displayName>RSSReader</displayName>
<description>RSSReader</description>
<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <domain>rss.cnn.com</domain>
        <port>80</port> 
        <connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>
        <socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>
        <maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>50</maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>           
        <!-- Following properties used by adapter's key manager for choosing specific certificate from key store  
        <sslCertificateAlias></sslCertificateAlias> 
        <sslCertificatePassword></sslCertificatePassword>
        -->     
    </connectionPolicy>
</connectivity>

<procedure name="getFeeds"/>
<procedure name="getFeedsFiltered"/>
```

**JS Code**

```
var busyIndicator = null;

function wlCommonInit(){
busyIndicator = new WL.BusyIndicator();
loadFeeds();
}

function loadFeeds(){
busyIndicator.show();

/*
 * The REST API works with all adapters and external resources, and is supported on the following hybrid environments: 
 * iOS, Android, Windows Phone 8, Windows 8. 
 * If your application supports other hybrid environments, see the tutorial for MobileFirst 6.3.
 */
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest("/adapters/RSSReader/getFeedsFiltered", WLResourceRequest.GET);
resourceRequest.setQueryParameter("params", "['technology']");
resourceRequest.send().then(
        loadFeedsSuccess,
        loadFeedsFailure
);
}


function loadFeedsSuccess(result){
WL.Logger.debug("Feed retrieve success");
busyIndicator.hide();
if (result.responseJSON.Items.length>0) 
    displayFeeds(result.responseJSON.Items);
else 
    loadFeedsFailure();
}

function loadFeedsFailure(result){
WL.Logger.error("Feed retrieve failure");
busyIndicator.hide();
WL.SimpleDialog.show("Engadget Reader", "Service not available. Try again later.", 
        [{
            text : 'Reload',
            handler : WL.Client.reloadApp 
        },
        {
            text: 'Close',
            handler : function() {}
        }]
    );
}

function displayFeeds(items){
var ul = $('#itemsList');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var li = $('<li/>').text(items[i].title);
    var pubDate = $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'pubDate'
    }).text(items[i].pubDate);

    li.append(pubDate);

    ul.append(li);
}
```

**Xcode Console log**

[image]

I had used the code give in the sample app.

Comment: Edit the question with your adapter invocation code as well as the Xcode log. Also make sure that the iPad device is connected to the same network as the server, otherwise it will fail.

Comment: @Idan I had edited the question with adapter code, js code and xcode Log.

Comment: It is working in Simulator but failing in device. So again, is the device connected to the same network as the Worklight Server?

Comment: @Idan Yes it uses the same network.

Comment: @IdanAdar We have to deploy the app in IBM work-light Server or not.When i run sample adapter app in android emulator it shows error like `[ERROR   ] FWLSE0332E: The application InvokingAdapterProcedures for the environment android does not exist on the server. Cannot register this client. [project InvokingAdapterProcedures]`

Comment: Of course you must deploy...

Comment: @IdanAdar To install IBM work-light server, should i be a customer of IBM and How to install IBM Work-light server in my windows 7.

Comment: If you want to install it on a remote server you must be a customer, yes.

Comment: @IdanAdar I want to develop a hybrid app which fetch RSS Feeds  and populates it in the UI. It should work on both iOS and android.I used adapter but it doesn't work.What are the procedures i had to do to achieve this in IBM Worklight?

Comment: You have a network error somewhere. Cannot help you right now.

Comment: Make sure you've deployed all environments. Open the MobileFirst console and make sure that your iPad environment appears. Also make sure your application is trying to connect to the correct IP.

Comment: @user2201624, in loadFeedFailure - print the result object, lets see what it contains.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to recreate this error.
Make sure these are the steps you've taken:

1. Import into MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.0 the "Invoking adapter procedures in hybrid applications" [sample project](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/invoking-adapter-procedures-hybrid-client-applications/)
2. Right-click on the adapter folder and select **Run As > Deploy MobileFirst Adapter**
3. Right-click on the project folder and select **New > MobileFirst Environment**, add iPad environment
4. Right-click on the iPad folder and select **Run As > Xcode project**
5. Click Run in Xcode

For me, by following the above steps I was able to successfully run the sample application in the iOS Simulator = the app was displayed and feeds were retrieved.

Comment: Did i need any external server for this deployment process.

Comment: If you are using the development server in Eclipse, it has an embedded server.  You are not the person who asked this question. Please don't mix questions.